# How to groupby key for custom class dataset in spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a class

```
public class Employee {
  int id;
  String name;
  String address;
}
```

...and a `Dataset<Employee>` in Spark, for example

```
Employee(1,"test1","test1")
Employee(1,"test2","test2")
Employee(2,"test3","test3")
```

Expected result

```
1---> [Employee(1,"test1","test1"),Employee(1,"test2","test2")]
2--->. Employee(2,"test3","test3")
```

I.e. I need to group the dataset by one of the fields (`id`), and get the result as a list of objects. How can I do this using Spark Java API.

Comment: did you try [groupByKey](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-groupbykey/)?

Comment: I tried but it looks for  overriding map function /function and couldn't get how we pass  id to group the object.